# Characterizing populations with stats.zscore grouping data

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have a DataFrame structured like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', np.random.randint(100)], ['B', np.random.randint(100)], ['B', np.random.randint(100)], ['A', np.random.randint(100)], ['A', np.random.randint(100)], ['B', np.random.randint(100)], ['B', np.random.randint(100)], ['A', np.random.randint(100)], ['A', np.random.randint(100)]], columns = ['type', 'value'])

   type value
0   A   14
1   B   7
2   B   84
3   A   53
4   A   83
5   B   90
6   B   78
7   A   60
8   A   23
```

What I would like to obtain is a table in which per each type column I have:

1. The mean of the values greater than a given stats.zscore
2. The mean of the values less than a given stats.zscore

If there was a single type, I would do this as follows:

```
outliers_mean = df.loc[np.abs(stats.zscore(df.value))>z_level].value.mean()
not_outliers_mean = df.loc[np.abs(stats.zscore(df.value))<z_level].value.mean()
```

However, since I'm considering multiple types, I can't do that because the stats.zscore should consider the population belonging to the single type.

Comment: Where does `stats` comes from? stats.zscore returns an array

Comment: I’m sorry I did not mention it was from scipy.stats

Comment: What happens with those that are equal to z_level?

Comment: It’s fine to exclude those values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, You could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from scipy import stats

# set seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)


df = pd.DataFrame([['A', np.random.randint(100)], ['B', np.random.randint(100)], ['B', np.random.randint(100)],
                   ['A', np.random.randint(100)], ['A', np.random.randint(100)], ['B', np.random.randint(100)],
                   ['B', np.random.randint(100)], ['A', np.random.randint(100)], ['A', np.random.randint(100)]],
                  columns=['type', 'value'])

# set z_level (for demo purposes)
z_level = 1.0

# get the z-score by type and mark those above z_level
df['outlier'] = np.abs(df.groupby('type').transform(stats.zscore)) > z_level

# compute mean
result = df.groupby(['type', 'outlier']).mean()

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
                  value
type outlier           
A    False    68.333333
     True     68.500000
B    False    51.000000
     True     53.000000
```

So in the end you have a mean aggregation by type and outlier mask value. If you want to exclude the values that are equal to `z_level` you can do that in a separate step.